# Python Openpyxl - Extracting Multiline cell value to perform split

Tags: python, split, openpyxl

I have a source excel file which contains multiline data in a single cell.

**table 1**

```
Product| Classification/Name
---------------------------
A0001   Seasonal Fruits
         MANGO
         ORANGE
        Exotic Fruits
         Dragon Fruit
         Strawberry
B0001   Vegetables
         ONIONS
         Tomato
```

I would like to have the data in below format.

**table 2**

```
Product| Classification| Name
----------------------------- 
A0001   Seasonal Fruits MANGO
A0001   Seasonal Fruits ORANGE
A0001   Exotic Fruits   Dragon Fruit
A0001   Exotic Fruits   Strawberry
B0001   Vegetables      ONIONS  
B0001   Vegetables      Tomato
```

I am not sure whether this is achievable via  python, but I like to give a try with the functions which I am aware of. Below is my code, I am able to load the data and split data by new line.

```
import openpyxl as pxl

src_path=r"C:\\Users\\TEST\\Documents\\test_new.xlsx"

wb=pxl.load_workbook(src_path)

ws=wb["Sheet1"]

row=ws.max_row

col=ws.max_column

for i in range(1,row):

    i=i+1

    mline=ws.cell(i,2).value

    splitdata= mline.split('\n')  #Split multiline data by "\n" new line.
```

Output of split is generated as a list.

**['Seasonal Fruits', ' MANGO', ' ORANGE', 'Exotic Fruits', ' Dragon Fruit', ' Strawberry']**

I need to navigate through the output list for each line of data and paste the same into another sheet as per the expected format above (table 2).

```
for listseq in splitdata: # code will navigate through each element in the list.
```

I am not sure how I can paste each item in the excel columns one by one. Because if I use loop counter, it will be incremented by 1 and all the items gets overwritten in a single cell. I am just stuck here, I can't find any solutions for this sort of scenario.

Your expert views are appreciated.

**--------- Revised Code ------------------- Just took one row for example**

```
import openpyxl as pxl
import pandas as pd

src_path=r"C:\\Users\\TEST\\Documents\\test_new.xlsx"

wb=pxl.load_workbook(src_path)

ws=wb["Sheet1"]

row=ws.max_row

col=ws.max_column

dest_path=r"C:\\Users\\TEST\\Documents\\FINAL.xlsx"

finalwb=pxl.load_workbook(dest_path)

finalws=finalwb["Sheet1"]


src_data=pd.read_excel(src_path)

df=pd.DataFrame(src_data)

first_col=(df.iloc[0,0])

second_col=(df.iloc[0,1])

final=(second_col.split('\n')) #split string by new line 

listindex=0 #set list index to zero

wscell=1   #set worksheet cell value

for j in final:

    wscell=wscell+1
    
    verify=final[listindex]

    finalws.cell(wscell,1).value=first_col

    if(len(verify)>=8):

       finalws.cell(wscell,2).value=verify

    else:

       finalws.cell(wscell,3).value=verify
       
    listindex=listindex+1

finalwb.save(dest_path)
```

**OUTPUT**

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeQjQ.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks AMC for the response, I was able to find the issue with the string.

Comment: However, I am not sure whether my requirement will be achievable via python. I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: It might be simpler if you use Pandas here, I suggest looking into it.

Comment: Thanks AMC for recommending pandas. I was so close with my expected format, only one of the field arrangement is missing, have added the revised code and current output to my question. I doing something wrong in one of the step, however I can't figure what is going wrong. Would you please help me here?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] with some simple test data?

Answer (score 0):

Scenario Not reproducible, No useful documentations available to re-produce this scenario.